# I can't connect my celery app with rabbitmq-server in Ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.810

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to run a celery app in python 3.810 and Ubuntu20.04 but I havent been able to connect to the rabbitmq-server.
The app is very simple:

```py
from celery import Celery
from time import sleep

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost//')


@app.task
def reverse(text):
    sleep(5)
    return text[::-1]
```

These are the libraries I have installed :

```
amqp==5.0.9 
asgiref==3.4.1 
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1 
billiard==3.6.4.0 
celery==5.2.3 
click==8.0.3 
click-didyoumean==0.3.0 
click-plugins==1.1.1 
click-repl==0.2.0 
Django==4.0.1 
kombu==5.2.3 
prompt-toolkit==3.0.24 
pytz==2021.3 
six==1.16.0 
sqlparse==0.4.2 
vine==5.0.0 
wcwidth==0.2.5 –
```

In the command line, when I run:   `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`

```
The log sends:

-------------- celery@DESKTOP-PA9QLQH v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Linux-4.4.0-19041-Microsoft-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2022-01-31 15:02:49
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f0e54d55a90
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.reverse

[2022-01-31 15:02:50,038: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: Server unexpectedly closed connection.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2022-01-31 15:02:52,042: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: Server unexpectedly closed connection.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)
```

I can access the rabbitmq-server from localhost:15672

I had tried all that i can find from stackoverflow, but nothing seems to help

I would appretiate the help

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? How did you set up all those bits and pieces that you didn't include in the above description? Also, please clarify what Python 3.810 is. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: These are the libraries I have installed :                                                                      amqp==5.0.9
asgiref==3.4.1
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.3
click==8.0.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
Django==4.0.1
kombu==5.2.3
prompt-toolkit==3.0.24
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5

Comment: Please don't add this info in comments but add them to the question. Make sure anyone trying to help you *knows* all steps to reproduce the issue. If in doubt, be explicit.

Comment: is it running on port `5672` or `15672`?

Comment: the aplication is running in port 5672, I can access the rabitmq directly through port 15672

Comment: what does the rabbitmq logs says? i know this is 3 months old issue but if anyone reading this and has similar issue then add rabbitmq logs too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try broker='pyamqp://rabbitmq:5672' instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).